# Lightning component calling wrong overloaded apex class method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that displays Knowledge Articles based on Topic IDs that it is configured for. This works great so I went to create my test coverage for it and discovered that the inserted test Knowledge Articles can only ever be 'Draft' making my tests fail since the apex class only looks for 'Online'. Instead of rewriting my component I decided to overload the apex method so that when called without the `status` parameter it passes in 'Online' allowing my tests to pass in 'Draft' instead. However, the first method signature does not get called from the component resulting in `null` for the status parameter.

Here is the component controller:

```
({
    "retrieveArticles" : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds");
        action.setParams({
            mainTopicId : component.get("v.mainTopicId"),
            secondaryTopicId : component.get("v.secondaryTopicId"),
            limitAmount : component.get("v.limitAmount")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                // handle SUCCESS
            }
            else if (component.isValid() && state === "ERROR") {
                // handle ERROR
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Here is the apex class:

```
public with sharing class KnowledgeArticleVersionCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds(String mainTopicId, String secondaryTopicId, Integer limitAmount) {
        return returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds(mainTopicId, secondaryTopicId, limitAmount, 'Online');
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds(String mainTopicId, String secondaryTopicId, Integer limitAmount, String status) {
        // build query string
        List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = Database.query(query);
        return articles;
    }
}
```

Is there something about the component that would cause it to not use the first signature, the one it should match, in place of the second one, which it shouldn't match?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think in general it's asking for trouble to overload a method and make *both* versions `@AuraEnabled`. You've seen that it will allow you to fire the method with missing parameters, so I suggest you just keep only the second method and check for a null:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds(String mainTopicId, String secondaryTopicId, Integer limitAmount, String status) {
    status = (status == null) ? 'Online' : status;
    // build query string
    List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = Database.query(query);
    return articles;
}
```

And if you have a scenario where overloads are useful in your Apex code but only one version ever needs to be called from Lightning, then only make that one overload `@AuraEnabled`.

Comment: I actually had already used that exact ternary statement in my code to work around this! Great minds I guess. Removing the AuraEnabled is a rather interesting thought. It seems to work but is still disappointing that this would be the issue. Any official word on AuraEnabled and overloaded methods?

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing official word too. In ASP.NET MVC 5 a similar thing happens but they use annotations to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: Just to add, it might be a best practice that if you have a method that will sometimes be called by Lightning and sometimes from Apex, create a wrapper with `@AuraEnabled` and a unique name and make that the only version Aura calls. That way even if the underlying implementation changes you can keep one constant name & signature for your Lightning component to talk to.

Comment: Was there ever any "official word".  My challenge is that I have global methods so cannot change the signature.  I had hoped that the ones marked with the @ Deprecated annotation would be ignored.  I'll try removing the @ AuraEnabled annotation and see if I can push to the packaging org even though they are global.  But I guess my question is do we know definitively which method will be chosen?  I made the naive assumption that the parameter types would govern that (I changed from a series of string params to a single param of type Object).

Comment: Here's an amazing finding.  I removed @ AuraEnabled from the method I don't want to be called.  But nevertheless, it is still getting hit by the Aura call from JS *instead* of the method that actually has the @ AuraEnabled annotation.  This is definite a bug and security loophole.

Comment: It's quite possible that in the 5 years since I first answered this, the behaviour of Aura has changed. There is a lot going on under the hood that is non-obvious. If you can reproduce this behaviour in an isolated dev org - Aura calls an overload you did NOT tag as AuraEnabled - that should definitely get logged as a bug. In the meantime see if maybe rearranging the order of the methods in the class changes anything?

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect that it uses the most complete signature like Java does.

(i.e. calling `myFunction()` will execute `myFunction(a,b){}`)

You could get around this by changing the signatures as follows:

```
public with sharing class KnowledgeArticleVersionCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds(String mainTopicId, String secondaryTopicId, Integer limitAmount) {
        return returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds(mainTopicId, secondaryTopicId, 'Online', limitAmount );
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> returnArticlesWithTwoTopicIds(String mainTopicId, String secondaryTopicId, String status, Integer limitAmount ) {
        // build query string
        List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = Database.query(query);
        return articles;
    }
}
```

Doing this, it should execute the method you expect vs the last one.

Comment: This was my first assumption as well. I've tested this however and I'm getting the same results. It's like there is something about AuraEnabled that causes a null status to always be passed in, which then causes the second signature to be used. All very strange.