# Parameter In AuraEnabled Method Is Null

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have encountered a strange issue with calling my `@AuraEnabled` method from Lightning.

The second parameter (which is a method overload) is consistently null when called from Lightning - but is never null when called `via executeAnonymous()`

Here is the first method definition:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ReportSummary getReportSummary(String reportName) {
  Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
  return getReportSummary(reportName,userId);
}
```

Here is the second definition (overload):

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ReportSummary getReportSummary(String reportName, Id userId){
  System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'USER ID: ' + userId);
  ReportSummary summary = new ReportSummary(userId, '');
  //ect ect...
  //the above system.debug prints out 'USER ID: null'
```

I call first (single parameter) method from Lightning.

If anyone can shed some light on this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126598/lightning-component-calling-wrong-overloaded-apex-class-method is related, possibly duplicate, but I'm not going to flag this because it'll auto-close if I do.

Comment: Dang, you are right. I had just worked out the answer too and was going to post - you may as well close, it's exactly the same. Funny how you found it and the system didn't.

Comment: It's okay, Caspar. The search system on SO leaves a bit to be desired, but usually I can coax an answer out of Google with some very specific keywords.

Comment: I might try that (a google search) next time. Good catch.

Comment: Oh, I should probably delete this question - yes?

Comment: You can leave it as a dupe, or delete it. Or you can ask on [meta]. I personally don't see anything wrong with leaving it as is.

Comment: Hmm, I'll leave it this time, as it may help catch searches that will eventually take people to the original question.