# Lightning Support for overloaded methods on server-side controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Apex method being overloaded as:

1. Method(String param1, String param2)
2. Method(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4)

Whatever number of parameters we pass from `helper.js` to the server-side action call, it always calls the 2nd one(method with 4 params) listed above.

Any specific reason of overloading not supported?

Comment: Similar to [Lightning component calling wrong overloaded apex class method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126598/lightning-component-calling-wrong-overloaded-apex-class-method)

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible and one theory is because even in JavaScript method overloading is not supported in a [traditional way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices).

In Lightning components an apex method is getting called in similar way, so it seems a method in Server side controller having maximum property gets the preference to be called.

Comment: Just to be clear, here overloading is done on apex side and not javascript. However, In Apex considering VF pages or component, overloading looks good.

Comment: Please refer the last line, server side controller method means of apex.

Comment: Yes, It seems to be. Anything doc/mention supporting your statement? It will help me close it.